# CCSprite efficient animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am animating 3 images (sprites) from off screen to the right into the middle of the screen. I have written the code below, but was wondering if there was a more efficient way of coding it.

```
-(void) displayMenu
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSizeInPixels];

    CCSprite* menuItemBottle = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"btn_i_have_norm.png"];
    menuItemBottle.position = ccp((screenSize.width * 2), 600.0f);
    menuItemBottle.contentSize = screenSize;
    menuItemBottle.scale = 1;
    [self addChild:menuItemBottle z:0 tag:4];

    CCSprite* menuItemAdvert = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"btn_see-ad_norm.png"];
    menuItemAdvert.position = ccp((screenSize.width * 2), 500.0f);
    menuItemAdvert.contentSize = screenSize;
    menuItemAdvert.scale = 1;
    [self addChild:menuItemAdvert z:0 tag:5];

    CCSprite* menuItemNoBottle = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"btn_dont-have_norm.png"];
    menuItemNoBottle.position = ccp((screenSize.width * 2), 400.0f);
    menuItemNoBottle.contentSize = screenSize;
    menuItemNoBottle.scale = 1;
    [self addChild:menuItemNoBottle z:0 tag:6];

    CGPoint newPointBottle = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.5f + 50, 600.0f);
    CCMoveTo *moveBottle = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.7f position:newPointBottle];
    CCSequence *sequenceBottle = [CCSequence actions:moveBottle, nil];
    [menuItemBottle runAction:sequenceBottle];

    CGPoint newPointAdvert = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.5f + 50, 500.0f);
    CCMoveTo *moveAdvert = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.7f position:newPointAdvert];
    CCSequence *sequenceAdvert = [CCSequence actions:moveAdvert, nil];
    [menuItemAdvert runAction:sequenceAdvert];

    CGPoint newPointNoBottle = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.5f + 50, 400.0f);
    CCMoveTo *moveNoBottle = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.7f position:newPointNoBottle];
    CCSequence *sequenceNoBottle = [CCSequence actions:moveNoBottle, nil];
    [menuItemNoBottle runAction:sequenceNoBottle];

}
```

Comment: Efficient as in less code or efficient as in runs quicker?

Comment: less code and if that runs quicker then great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get all of the actions down to a single line.  The first one would end up looking like this:

[menuItemBottle runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.7f position:ccp(screenSize.width *      0.5f + 50, 600.0f)]];

If you'd prefer to define the position outside of the action then you could continue to do that.  Just FYI a CCSequence is for when you want to run actions on the same object consecutively (i.e. a move action runs and when it's done a rotate action runs).

Also I don't believe you need to set the scale to 1 for each of the images as I believe it is already set to that.